# How to center a SF Symbols image vertically in UITabBarItem?

Tags: ios, uikit, uitabbar, uitabbaritem, sf-symbols

I am using SF Symbols images as tab images in my iOS app by assigning them as follows:

```swift
self.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "ellipsis")
```

This results in all images being top-aligned, but I would like to have them centered vertically.

What do I have to do for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently SF symbols are rendered with system font size by default. So if you add a baseline offset of half that size to the ellipsis symbol you could almost perfectly center it vertically that way.

It's only almost perfect because ellipsis symbol has a height of its own which is not accounted for by this solution, even if it is not much.

```
self.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "ellipsis")!.withBaselineOffset(fromBottom: UIFont.systemFontSize / 2)
```

Comment: For some symbols the right offset must be chosen manually - but yes, that's the right solution. Thanks!

Comment: Finally a solution that works. Thanks a lot! Ps. min iOS 13 required.

Answer (score 5):

The best solution, which will make your button identical to "tabBarSystemItem: .more", but with the possibility of removing the title and applying Configuration is the following:

```
self.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "ellipsis", withConfiguration: 
UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(weight: .black))!.imageWithoutBaseline()
```

Comment: imageWithoutBaseline() did the trick for me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the image insets on the `UITabBarItem` to shift your icons down 6 or 7px (depending on your icon size).

#### In code:

I've done this by creating a subclass of `UITabBarController` and adding this code to the bottom of my `viewDidLoad` method:

```swift
tabBar.items?.forEach({
  $0.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)
})
```

(You could also do this in your ViewController classes, if that's where you configure each of their tab bar items.)

#### In storyboards:

You can also do it using storyboards by selecting your TabBarItem in the storyboard and adjusting the insets in the info panel:

[image: Adjusting image insets in Storyboard]

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that imageinset values from the storyboard are not applied to SF Symbols images.