# SwiftUI TabBar Ellipsis Not Vertically Centered

Tags: ios, swiftui, sf-symbols

I'm just getting started with a SwiftUI app and so the first thing I'm doing is getting my navigation set up.

I'm starting with a very simple TabBar using all default stuff, including SF Symbols for the icons.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ActivityView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                    Text("Activity")
                }
            
            DiscoverView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    Text("Discover")
                }
            
            MoreView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                    Text("More")
                }
            
        }
    }
}
```

It's rendering like this:

[image: ellipsis is aligned near top of tab bar]

Why is the ellipsis not vertically centered? I thought one of the big selling points of SF Symbols is that they would all line up with each other.

I'm really confused.

Comment: Probably a `tabItem` bug.

Comment: Try to remove the [baseline information](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/3294229-imagewithoutbaseline) of the ellipsis Image. Or see similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58185158/how-to-center-a-sf-symbols-image-vertically-in-uitabbaritem) for other possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Xcode 12.5.1 & 13.0 Beta 1**

The 'ellipsis' symbol is still rendering to the top of the tabItem frame, and the frame and offsets cannot be modified directly in SwiftUI.  I have resolved it by wrapping the image in a UIImage and removing the baseline.

```
    MoreView()
        .tabItem {
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "ellipsis")!.imageWithoutBaseline())
            Text("More")
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! This will come in handy

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much.